# Get the Keyboard keycodes keys in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, qt, enums, keycode

I need to get the keycodes from keyboard input (but after) in Linux, i been able to find
the keycodes in Windows only.

Using a enum i can make it cross-platform, heres is a piece (not complete, is too large) of
the enum code:

```
  enum e_IWEKey
{
  Unknown = 0,

// Digits / Numbers
D0,
D1,
D2,
D3,
D4,
D5,
D6,
D7,
D8,
D9,

// Letters
A,
B,
C,
D,
E,
F,
G,
H,
I,
J,
K,
L,
M,
N,
O,
P,
Q,
}
```

And here another piece the respective Win32API Keycodes.

```
    #ifdef _WIN32
    # include <WinUser.h>

  inline e_IWEKey getKey(uchar OSKey)
  {
    switch (OSKey)
    {
      // Digits / Numbers
    case 0x30: return IWEKeys::D0;
    case 0x31: return IWEKeys::D1;
    case 0x32: return IWEKeys::D2;
    case 0x33: return IWEKeys::D3;
    case 0x34: return IWEKeys::D4;
    case 0x35: return IWEKeys::D5;
    case 0x36: return IWEKeys::D6;
    case 0x37: return IWEKeys::D7;
    case 0x38: return IWEKeys::D8;
    case 0x39: return IWEKeys::D9;

      // Letters
    case 0x41: return IWEKeys::A;
    case 0x42: return IWEKeys::B;
    case 0x43: return IWEKeys::C;
    case 0x44: return IWEKeys::D;
    case 0x45: return IWEKeys::E;
    case 0x46: return IWEKeys::F;
    case 0x47: return IWEKeys::G;
    case 0x48: return IWEKeys::H;
    case 0x49: return IWEKeys::I;
    case 0x4A: return IWEKeys::J;
    case 0x4B: return IWEKeys::K;
    case 0x4C: return IWEKeys::L;
    case 0x4D: return IWEKeys::M;
    case 0x4E: return IWEKeys::N;
    case 0x4F: return IWEKeys::O;
    case 0x50: return IWEKeys::P;
    case 0x51: return IWEKeys::Q;
    case 0x52: return IWEKeys::R;
    case 0x53: return IWEKeys::S;
    case 0x54: return IWEKeys::T;
    case 0x55: return IWEKeys::U;
    case 0x56: return IWEKeys::V;
    case 0x57: return IWEKeys::W;
    case 0x58: return IWEKeys::X;
    case 0x59: return IWEKeys::Y;
    case 0x5A: return IWEKeys::Z;

      // Function Keys
    case VK_F1: return IWEKeys::F1;
    case VK_F2: return IWEKeys::F2;
    case VK_F3: return IWEKeys::F3;
    case VK_F4: return IWEKeys::F4;
    case VK_F5: return IWEKeys::F5;
    case VK_F6: return IWEKeys::F6;
    case VK_F7: return IWEKeys::F7;
    case VK_F8: return IWEKeys::F8;
    case VK_F9: return IWEKeys::F9;
    case VK_F10: return IWEKeys::F10;
    case VK_F11: return IWEKeys::F11;
    case VK_F12: return IWEKeys::F12;
    case VK_F13: return IWEKeys::F13;
    case VK_F14: return IWEKeys::F14;
    case VK_F15: return IWEKeys::F15;
    case VK_F16: return IWEKeys::F16;
    case VK_F17: return IWEKeys::F17;
    case VK_F18: return IWEKeys::F18;
    case VK_F19: return IWEKeys::F19;
    case VK_F20: return IWEKeys::F20;
    case VK_F21: return IWEKeys::F21;
    case VK_F22: return IWEKeys::F22;
    case VK_F23: return IWEKeys::F23;
    case VK_F24: return IWEKeys::F24;
    }
    }
    #endif
```

but i never find the Linux keycodes, i need to use the internal Linux API (or POSIX), the X11 API or toolkit-specific API? (as Qt).
 Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use qt, there is [Qt::Key enum](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt.html#Key-enum).

Base on how keys are defined in qt, I think key codes would not change between linux and windows...